# How to use TDengine 's query_a() api in c

Tags: c, asynchronous, tdengine

By reading TDengine C API reference. I see that TDengine support async APIs and one of then which is called `query_a()`. And I'm new to C. I want to call this API in multiple thread.
The API instructions are as follow:

```
   // taos: The database connection returned by calling taos_connect()
   // sql: The SQL statement needed to execute
   // fp: User-defined callback function, whose third parameter code is used to indicate whether the operation is successful, 0 for success, and negative number for failure (call taos_errstr() to get the reason for failure). When defining the callback function, it mainly handles the second parameter TAOS_RES *, which is the result set returned by the query
   // param：the parameter for the callback    
    void taos_query_a(TAOS *taos, const char *sql, void (*fp)(void *param, TAOS_RES *, int code), void *param); Execute SQL statement asynchronously.
    
    // res: The result set returned when taos_query_a() callback.
    // fp: Callback function. Its parameter param is a user-definable parameter construct passed to the callback function; 
    // numOfRows is the number of rows of data obtained (not a function of the entire query result set). 
    // In the callback function, applications can get each row of the batch records by calling taos_fetch_rows() forward iteration. 
    // After reading all the records in a block, the application needs to continue calling 
    // taos_fetch_rows_a() in the callback function to obtain the next batch of records for 
    // processing until the number of records returned (numOfRows) is zero (the result is returned)
    // or the number of records is negative (the query fails).
    void taos_fetch_rows_a(TAOS_RES *res, void (*fp)(void *param, TAOS_RES *, int numOfRows), void *param);
    Get the result set of asynchronous queries in batch, which can only be used with taos_query_a().
```

more details can refer [API reference][1]

I don't know how execute mounts of query_a() in muliplte thread, and how could I know that the callback method have done. Can some help?
[1]: https://tdengine.com/docs/en/v2.0/connector#c-cpp

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with C, But you can reference TDengine's repo, They also have sample code for this api.
you can reference the usage of the query_a() at [github query_a example in C](https://github.com/taosdata/TDengine/blob/d10cce1e98f9362468d325e3f0c6bec1c7e866e2/examples/c/apitest.c#L251-L263)